# how to create directories through shell scripts from command line?

Tags: shell, unix, for-loop, mkdir

I want to create directories with given names through shell script in one go.. rather than writing mkdir command for n number of times to create n number of directories.

Comment: Including actual examples of the problem you are trying to solve makes it so much easier to help. The answer below is correct for one interpretation of your problem. I think you mean `mkdir -p /nonexisting/dir/nonesuch/v2` which will create that set of directories, even though none of them exist. In the future, use  `man mkdir` to see available options. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mkdir` is able to take any number of arguments, so:

```
mkdir a b c
```

would make the trick without the need of any script.

If you really want comma separated list then:

```
 mkdir `echo a,b,c | sed -e 's/,/ /g'`
```

will make it.

Comment: thanks.... I'm not much aware of unix commands. So I wasn't thought that way. Thank you for pointing that :)